# SSAS 2005 fact from a view, multiple partitions from queries ok?

Tags: ssas

In my case, the fact (sales) is from a view on a SQL Server 2005 database. The view is for two years of data. When it comes to partition design I want to build one partition for each year. So can I use different quires to build the partitions? What's the rule here? Is it I only needs to make the query returns exact same columns as the view? If yes, is dsv only servers as a meta data describing the relationship between facts and dimensions but actual fact data is from the partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly as you described.